# Library routine called out of sequence from sqlite3_open

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am trying to create/open an sqlite database when the application first loads. But I am constantly getting the error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: Failed to open because library routine called out of sequence'**
Below is my code in the main viewcontroller file:

```
- (NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];
}

- (void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to open because %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Database opened");
    }
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self openDB];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Your database is already opened without close and you are trying to reopen the DB.

Comment: This is happening on the first run on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasone for this error is that you called `sqlite3_errmsg` after `sqlite3_close`; you get a harmless error that happened during cleanup.

You must call `sqlite3_errmsg` before `sqlite3_close` to get the actual error.

Comment: Error changed to ***... unable to open database file***

Comment: Now you know what the problem is (the path does not exist, or you are not allowed to access it).

Comment: How do i fix this? I followed a video tutorial. This code should work as per the tutorial. What changes do i need to make?

Comment: Does that tutorial really tell you to use `NSDocumentationDirectory`, and not `NSDocumentDirectory`?

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.