# SQLite3 nsInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'library routine called out of sequence'`

This is the error message I receive.

ExposureViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)saveExposure:(id)sender {
    double sfd = [self.sfdField.text doubleValue];
    double thickness = [self.thicknessField.text doubleValue];
    int filmFactor = 35;
    double mAmins = 5.5;
    double density = 2.5;
    NSString *setUsed = @"Bay One Set";
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSString *theDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currDate];

    Connection *dataBase = [[Connection alloc]init];

    [dataBase openDB];

    [dataBase saveTable:theDate withFieldSFD:sfd withFieldFilmFactor:filmFactor withFieldSet:setUsed withFieldThickness:thickness withFieldkV:kvValue withFieldmA:maValue withFieldmAmins:mAmins withFieldDensity:density];
}
```

This is my IBAction to call for the data to be saved, in my exposureViewController.m

It connects to Connection.h for database queries etc.

Connection.m

```
-(void)saveTable:(NSString *)dateField withFieldSFD:(float)field3 withFieldFilmFactor:(int)field4 withFieldSet:(NSString *)field5 withFieldThickness:(float)field6 withFieldkV:(int)field7 withFieldmA:(int)field8 withFieldmAmins:(float)field9 withFieldDensity:(float)field10
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO exposures ('theDate', 'sfd', 'filmFactor', 'setUsed', 'thickness', 'kV', 'mA', 'mAmins', 'density') VALUES ('%@', '%.2f', '%i', '%@', '%.2f', '%i', '%i', '%.5f', '%.2f')", dateField, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10];

    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"datasaved");
    }
}
```

So I keep throwing this error, previously before adding the openDB method I would call an `out of memory` error. But straight after sorting that I've ran into this. Also, if this helps here is how the table was created.

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ( "
                 "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, '%@' TEXT '%@' FLOAT, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' TEXT, '%@' FLOAT, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' FLOAT, '%@' FLOAT);", tableName, field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library routine called out of sequence from sqlite3\_open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783059/library-routine-called-out-of-sequence-from-sqlite3-open)

Comment: I think you're quite right.. Thank you for linking me, Now I get my error message I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the database before asserting the error.

After a shuffle I'm now receiving the real error that throws the SQLITE_OK handler.